# $this->Auth->user() is NULL in AppController

Tags: xampp, cakephp-3.7

I am encountering a null value `$user = $this->Auth->user();` in this line of code in the AppController.
So whenever I use `$user['username];`it gives of this error

> Trying to access array offset on value of type null
>   [APP/Controller\AppController.php, line 75]

Please help.

Comment: That means that no authenticated user data is present, which can have various causes, from authentication not being applied, to authenticated data not being stored. You'd need to debug this a bit, and show your auth config and login code. ps. please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: Ore even just when the visitor is not logged in at all, which is presumably a quite common situation that your code needs to account for.